# Nothing happens when clicking a button (VS c#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to get a response when i click a button. But when i click the button nothing happens...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {         
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Text = "hi";
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
        }
    }
}
```

When I added the button VS did not add the method to the script, so im not sure if button1_Click is the right syntax, it does not give any errors though.

Comment: double click on button in design view. it will create the method for you

Comment: oh okay thanks a bunch !

Comment: More importantly, it'll register the event handler on the button (check the generated code in `Form1.Designer.cs` after clicking the button)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verify in the designer code "form1.designer.cs" that your method is set as handler for the Click event. If not, subscribe to the event:

```
button1.Click += button1_Click;
```

You can also verify it in the property pane of your button:

[image]